# Disable defaultFocusHighlightEnabled in the android part for a Xamarin.Forms application

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

In a xamarin.forms application running in an android 8 device I want to disable the controls highlights when I'm using a physical keyboard (this is a new android 8 behavior)

The android documentation says that I should set android:defaultFocusHighlightEnabled="false" for that

I tried to add that in my manifest file but the highlight continues appearing

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:defaultFocusHighlightEnabled="false" android:versionName=
```

Where can I set that globally?

Comment: `android:defaultFocusHighlightEnabled` is view's property. You need setup for the view one by one.

Comment: Do you know or have any information about how can I do that for a xamarin.forms app?

Comment: Do you want to set this property for all the views?

Comment: why dont you just add it to the values styles theme?

Comment: @RodrigoJuarez, like G.hakim said, you can use Application's theme :`<item name="android:defaultFocusHighlightEnabled">false</item>`.

Comment: Yes, I want to set the value for all the views

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I was able to solve the issue with the comments

In my styles.xml file (referenced in the main activity) I added the entry in the theme

**MainActivity.cs**

```
[Activity(Label = "Sage Service Ops", Icon = "@drawable/icon", MainLauncher = false, Theme = "@style/MyTheme", ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation)]
public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsApplicationActivity
```

**styles.xml**

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
  <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyTheme.ActionBarStyle</item>
  <item name="android:defaultFocusHighlightEnabled">false</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 5):

I solved this by editing styles.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

......

    <style name="LaunchTheme"parent="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar">
 
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/launch_background</item>
        <item name="android:defaultFocusHighlightEnabled">false</item>
    </style>

    <style name="NormalTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/white</item>
        <item name="android:defaultFocusHighlightEnabled">false</item>
    </style>

......

</resources>
```

Simply fix the green border bug by just adding the below code to styles.xml

```
<item name="android:defaultFocusHighlightEnabled">false</item>
```

Comment: For those who don't know: `styles.xml` is located in `/android/app/src/main/res/values/`.