# Android. Unexpected fade (dim) background after lost focus

Tags: android, background, focus, fade

I observe a strange effect in various scenarios, which boil down to the fact that after the EditText loses focus, the background of the application is faded (dimmed).

I have attached link to the simple [test application](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1XydlRx_6rUi_Q-P5KaRsspgQdUkyCLZd/view?usp=sharing).

The flow to reproduce:

1. Run app. Yuo will see the following (Just EditText is on the screen and it is focused. Background is also white (250,250,250)).
   [After start application. Background is white](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l0voJ.png)
2. Press . Yuo will see the following:
   [List apperead on the screen and background is faded (231,231,231)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ma1Eo.png)
3. Press 'A' char on the keyboard (Emulator used for the test). You will see:
   [List with NOT focused EditText. Background is still faded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w3mn2.png)
4. Finally focus EditText using touch and see:
   [List with focused EditText. Background returned to the normal state (not faded)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D5uYC.png)

This scenario is just a sample. I can get it in some other cases.

What is the reason of this behavior? How to get rid of this effect completely?

Thanks for possible answers.

Upd. Looks like it is automatic highlighting effect when View get focus. So we need to disable this effect.

Comment: Looks like the default highlight behaivor can be around of using view.setDefaultFocusHighlightEnabled (false) or similar way. It works. You can refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49541354/disable-defaultfocushighlightenabled-in-the-android-part-for-a-xamarin-forms-app.